# Custom taxonomy check box now showing up

Tags: functions, custom-taxonomy

Registering a custom taxonomy so I can use has_term, for some reason the checkbox isn't showing up in the editor.

```
function custom_taxonomy() {
   if( !term_exists( 'Yes', 'layout' ) ) {
       wp_insert_term(
           'Yes',
           'layout',
           array(
             'description' => 'This is an example category created with wp_insert_term.'
           )
       );
   }



    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Small Featured Image?', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'layout', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Taxonomy', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used items', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $capabilities = array(
   'manage_terms'               => '',
        'edit_terms'                 => '',
        'delete_terms'               => '',
        'assign_terms'               => 'edit_posts', // <-- change this one to a desired cap if you need to be able to assign them(you could use manage_options for admins only)
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => false,
        'show_tagcloud'              => false,
        'capabilities'               => $capabilities,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'layout', array( 'post' ), $args );




}
// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy', 0 );
```

The custom taxonomy shows up but there's no checkbox, what gives?

Comment: trying to insert a term into a tax before registering it seem kinda wierd

Comment: True. That fixed it.